# Repetitions of a String

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, arraylist

I am trying to get all the repetitions of a string from a given ArrayLists. I achieved this by using the following code:

```
public static void howmany (ArrayList <String> list)
{
    for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i)+ ": " + Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)));
    }
}
```

However, the output is the following:

> sorry: 4 bat: 1 sorry: 4 sorry: 4 sorry: 4 train: 2 train: 2 teddy: 2
>   teddy: 2 ball: 2 ball: 2

The code in the Runner class is :

```
ArrayList<String> toys = new ArrayList <String>();

String[] toys1 = {"sorry", "bat", "sorry", "sorry", "sorry", "train", "train", "teddy", "teddy", "ball", "ball"};

for (int i=0; i<toys1.length;i++)
{
    toys.add(toys1[i]);
}

Toys.howmany(toys);
```

Is there a way that the output doesn't repeat the words?
For example, that it just says:

> sorry: 4, bat: 1, train: 2, teddy: 2, ball: 2

I am a beginner and I am still trying to learn java logic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store values that you already printed and then check everytime you print value so you will eliminate duplicates.

For example you could do this:

```
public static void howmany (ArrayList <String> list)
{
    Set<String> processed = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
    {
        if(!processed.contains(list.get(i))) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)));
            processed.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashMap` for this purpose. First, traverse the whole `ArrayList` and add those strings as keys and make their value as `1` if you found new strings or increment the value of the corresponding key.

```
if(myMap.contains("foo"))
    myMap.put("foo",myMap.get("foo")++);
else
    myMap.put("foo",1);
```

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you 2 simple ways.

You can use a set to check duplicates. Create a hashset and add list.get(i) to it use the return value in your if condition. A add method of hashset will retrun true only if it is not already added in the set, else it will return a false.

Alternatively, you can create a hashset from the list and iterate over your hashset to eliminate any duplicates.

Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

just use hashmap,like this

```
String[] toys1 = {"sorry", "bat", "sorry", "sorry", "sorry", "train", "train", "teddy", "teddy", "ball", "ball"};
Map<String,Integer> toyMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(String str:toys1){
    if(toyMap.containsKey(str)){
        toyMap.put(str, toyMap.get(str)+1);
    }else{
        toyMap.put(str, 1);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : toyMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+"  : "+entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(n) solution using hashmap:

```
 public static void howmany (List <String> list)
  {
        Map<String,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

        for (String item:list)
        {
            counts.put(item, counts.getOrDefault(item,0)+1);          

        }
    System.out.println(counts);
  }



  public static void main(String []args){

     String[] toys1 = {"sorry", "bat", "sorry", "sorry", "sorry", "train", "train", "teddy", "teddy", "ball", "ball"};


    howmany(Arrays.<String>asList(toys1));
  }
```